# How to create a custom procedure or something like that

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi im new to Android and just wanted to ask if there is a way to create a custom procedure for example i want to call up the following code in onStart by t_test and if i call this code the programm should do this: `Toast toast = Toast.makeText(TimerTestActivity.this, "Hallo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();`
I want to do this because I think its clean and if I want to call this code more often its smaller.
I Hope somebody can help me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is somewhat vague, but I'll give it a shot.

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    cookToast("Hallo");
}
public void cookToast(String msg){
    Toast.makeText(TimerTestActivity.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You can make a method like this, you'll have to put this method declaration outside of your onStart, but you can call it from inside.